# Python Recursion Limit Work Around

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm currently working on a python problem:

Given a number line from -infinity to +infinity. You start at 0 and can go either to the left or to the right. The condition is that in i’th move, you take i steps. In the first move take 1 step, second move 2 steps and so on. 
Hint: 3 can be reached in 2 steps (0, 1) (1, 3). 2 can be reached in 3 steps (0, 1) (1,-1) (-1, 2)

a) Find the optimal number of steps to reach position 1000000000 and -1000000000.

I have managed to code the following:

```
def steps(source, step, dest):
    if abs(source) > dest:
        return sys.maxint
    if source == dest:
        return step

    pos = steps(source+step+1, step+1, dest)
    neg = steps(source-step-1, step+1, dest)

    return min(pos, neg)
```

The problem is that even though this function gives me the correct answer, it cannot extend to the range asked of me. Is there a work around for this or would I have to go about a different method of solving the question?

Comment: This feels like a job for [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) / [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Comment: It seems it should be simple to outline a dynamic programming algorithm, but I'm not sure how well it would scale to the given numbers.

Comment: @Robᵩ Nah, simple greedy.

Answer (score 4):

I think this can actually be solved with pen, paper and a calculator. I don't want to spoil the entire puzzle (sounds like homework), but I'll give some hints.

Imagine we just walk in the direction of 1000000000, i.e. we take steps to the right each time.

- Can you come up with a closed formula that tells you where you are after `n` steps?
- From there, can you compute how many steps it'll take until you "overshoot" past 1000000000? This is obviously a lower bound for the required number of steps, because with fewer steps we simply can't cover the distance.
- Where exactly do you end up at the moment you overshoot?
- Finally, can you modify your path in such a way that you end up exactly on target, in the same amount of steps?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid recursion you can save the state in a list, I'll explain better.

```
def steps(source, step, dest):
    q = Queue()
    q.put((0,1))
    while True:
        source, ste = q.get()
        if abs(source) > dest:
            return sys.maxint
        if source == dest:
            return step

        q.put(source+step+1, step+1)
        q.put(source-step-1, step+1)
```

Doing so you save in the queue the position to check, and every time you check a position which is not the final one you will add the new 2 position at the end of the queue. This method also garantee that the solution found is the shortest. 
To improve speed even more you cold save a list of number already visited which will stop the research every time you will find the same number again, this will speed up the task a lot

Comment: This technically avoids recursion, but is conceptually equivalent, and the program will run out of memory anyway because it is trying to explore an exponentially-sized search space.

Comment: you are both right, but I think the limit of recursion is way lower than the limit of a queue, in addition old items will be removed so some memory will be freed which doesn't happen with recursion.